# jQuery doesn't display Hebrew

Tags: jquery, utf-8, hebrew

I am using jQuery to validate a form.
I have at my html's head: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

I have utf-8 on my scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="validate.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

My html page shows Hebrew just fine as long as it's not though the jQuery code.
Any Hebrew character printed trough the jQuery (through the script in validate.js) prints out as: ����

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe jQuery does'nt support ancient languages ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Open all your html, css, js (all client files that relevant to this project) using notepad and save them with utf-8 encoding. Notice that this might change the hebrew text and the content a little. After that you should see hebrew.

Good Luck!

Comment: That did the job.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: you are my hero

Comment: I have similar situation.
All files are encoded as windows-1255

I have ~20K files on a live site, it is irrelevant to change the encoding in all of them.