# Force String in JavaScript to be UTF-8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, utf-8

my JS-File is UTF-8 encoded, my html document also.

I also have this in the head part of the HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Every umlaut that I typed in the HTML is displayed properly.

But if I try to set a new value with `$('#test').text('Test öäü')` I get `Test Ã¶Ã¤Ã¼`.

How is this possible? Even `console.`debug/log and `alert()` display the same.

I also tried to set the `charset` attribute on my script-tag, but nothing worked.

Can anybody help me with this issue?

Comment: You should check you IDE and database content and charset.

Comment: There is no database content, everything is static. As I mentioned above, I checked the files, all files are encoded with UTF-8.

Comment: try see encoding in browser settings

Comment: In a new HTML file with only the basic elements, the issue is reproduced? Is it browser specific?

Comment: 1. Is that code in a separate JavaScript file, or in your HTML file? 2. In your browser's network tab, check the response headers for the relevant file and make sure there's a `Content-Type` header that correctly gives the `charset="utf-8"`, e.g., `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8` for HTML, or `Content-Type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8` for JavaScript. I mean, fundamentally, with the correct content type(s), [that works](http://jsbin.com/eqAVAwOd/1).

Comment: `<meta charset="utf-8" />` is this tag correctly available inspect with firebug/webinspector.

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder, I found the issue. I use minify to combine my css/js and minify had $min_serveOptions['contentTypeCharset'] set to  iso-8859-1. Thank you! :)

Comment: [jQuery doesn't display Hebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10746858/6209936)
I have problem like yours. And this answer resolve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I use minify to combine my css/js and minify had $min_serveOptions['contentTypeCharset'] set to iso-8859-1.