# Hebrew is question mark in html

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am building web application using bootstrap and angularjs.
in html I have the meta tag:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

the navbar items written in hebrew, and it's OK.
when I write hebrew content in the conatiner div, it's also OK.

but when I write hebrew in the partials (which are displayed in the ng-view) I get question marks.

google didn't help.

any ideas?

Comment: its possible that the font you are using to doesn't support those characters.

Comment: I tried to change font, but it didn't change much. the menu items (in hebrew) were changed, but the question marks in ng-view stayed.

Comment: Can you post some of your code so we can take a look? Otherwise can't be sure...

Comment: I haven't done anything special with the code. I have the meta tag:
**<meta charset="utf-8">**
and I have the **<div class=container ng-view></div>**
if I remove the ng-view and write the content in hebrew it is OK. but If I have a partial (in a sepparate file)  in hebrew then I have question marks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10746268/jquery-doesnt-display-hebrew)

I needed to open the partial html files (that I got from angular seed) with notepad, and "save As" encoding = utf8

Comment: Thanks. I had this issue, however couldn't remember. :)